# Single word for person entitled to receive a sales commission

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives, synonyms, terminology

I need a fairly specific single word for a person who is entitled to receive a sales commission. "Agent" for example isn't specific enough.

A short phrase is also usable. Adjectives ditto. The underlying field is accounting.

This is actually for use as a database table name, which is why it needs to be fairly specific, but it's an English language question all right ;-)

Comment: Check on relevant domain if a term already exists, before coining one of your own.

Comment: @Kris I have no intention whatsoever of coining my own. Hence this question.

Comment: So please check on relevant domain first, or on SO.

Comment: http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/128026/commission-agent

Comment: @Kris I'm asking here because here is more appropriate than SO, as it isn't a programing question *per se,* but an English language question. As I've already stated. I've also neither expressed nor implied any intention to coin a term of my own. If you don't want to contribute to the discussion you're certainly going the right way about it. "Commission agent" is polite for "bookmaker" in some countries.

Answer (score 3):

Universally in sales environments, those people are referred to as "on-commission", which leads me to believe there is no shorter word.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Bit of a mouthful for a table name ;-) I'm inclined to agree that there doesn't appear to be any single term.

Answer (score 0):

In many instances such a person may be referred to as a "contractor". The term infers that a fee or commission is to be paid on completion of an assigned task.

Comment: This isn't really a forum to find answers for your specific naming needs. You should keep your questions within the scope of the site.